# Firebase Update email address HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a HTML page where a user can update their email address. I've attached an event listener that will update Firebase with the email address the user supplies in the form.

The code below gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateEmail' of null at HTMLButtonElement.

updateEmail appears in the Firebase docs, so I'm confused. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for your help!

The Js

```
"use strict";
(function () {

// get the form elements from HTML
var acctEmail = document.getElementById('acctEmail'),
    acctPassword = document.getElementById('acctPassword'),
    btnUpdate = document.getElementById('btnUpdate'),
    btnDeleteAcct = document.getElementById('btnDeleteAcct'),
    auth = firebase.auth(),
    user = firebase.auth().currentUser, // get the current user
    emailtoval = acctEmail.value, // get the email from acctEmail input field
    email = JSON.stringify(emailtoval); // convert email to json string


// update email
btnUpdate.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
     user.updateEmail(email).then(function() {
        // Update successful.
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
         });
    });


})(); // end Js file wrapper
```

Here's the HTML Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
     <!-- head include -->
    <% include includes/head.ejs %>
</head>

<body id="accountbody">
    <!-- header include -->
    <% include includes/header.ejs %>

    <main>
        <h1> Manage Your Account </h1>

        <!-- begin account details form -->
        <h2>Update your account</h2>
        <div class="updateacctform">
            <input id="acctEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email">

            <input id="acctPassword" type="password" 
placeholder="Password">

            <button id="btnUpdate" class="updateacctbtn">Update
            </button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h2>Delete your account</h2>
            <button id="btnDeleteAcct" class="deleteacctbtn"> Delete 
Account
            </button>
        </div>

    </main>

    <!-- footer include -->
    <% include includes/footer.ejs %>

    <!-- Js files -->
    <script src="javascripts/account.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where you are initializing you Firebase app instance. You are also not waiting for the current user to be ready. You need to call the following:

```
// Initialize Firebase app.
firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Wait for auth state to be ready.
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is logged in. you can access firebase.auth().currentUser.
    // You can now perform operations on the user.
  } else {
    // No user logged in.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I got it working. I'll post it here as an edit to your answer.

Comment: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
        if (firebaseUser) {
            var newEmail = document.getElementById('acctEmail').value;
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
            user.updateEmail(newEmail).then(function() {
                // successful
                user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
                // Email sent
                }, function(error) {
                  // Error
                });
            }, function(error) {
              // Error
                });
            }
        });